# Data extracting from Cassandra DB into excel using Python

Tags: python, cassandra

I am trying to extract the cassandra db results into excel using Python. When i run the below code, i am getting the following error. I couldn't able to resolve the following issue. Can someone please help me? This error appears for all columns.

Error: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute "Column1"

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra.auth import PlainTextAuthProvider
from cassandra.query import dict_factory

auth_provider = PlainTextAuthProvider(username=CASSANDRA_USER, password=CASSANDRA_PASS)
cluster = Cluster(contact_points= ["host"], port=xxx, auth_provider=auth_provider)
session = cluster.connect("keyspace")
session.row_factory = dict_factory
sql_query = "SELECT * FROM db.tablename"
dictionary = {"column1":[],"column2":[],"column3":[],"column4":[]}

for row in session.execute(sql_query):

    dictionary["column1"].append(row.column1)
    dictionary["column2"].append(row.column2)
    dictionary["column3"].append(row.column3)
    dictionary["column4"].append(row.column4)

df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)
df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\data.xlsx')
```

Comment: What is your schema?